# Recursion issue when writing a "Pretext" aware version of Lens.para

Tags: haskell, recursion, haskell-lens, recursion-schemes

I've been trying to build a replacement for `Lens.para` that provides lensed contexts to the para function as it does its work. However, I seem to have made an error in the recursion somewhere.

According to my understanding of it, `Lens.para` is a paramorphism function over **values** in a recursive algebraic data type. That is, it uses `plated` and takes a function that explodes an options list to be used for traversing across the "self-similar syntax space" of a piece of data, all the while making its traversal data-context available to the function as it does its work. Its type is `Lens.Plated a => (a -> [r] -> r) -> a -> r`, where `[r]` is the list of data-context values, and `a` is the type of each value which plated knows how to "look into" successive levels of.

The **extremely simple toy example** data type I'm using to proof-of-concept this is as follows:

`data EExp a
  = ELit a
  | EAdd (EExp a) (EExp a)
  deriving (Show, Eq)`

So, here is my code, including both the existing working version of `showOptions` and my new version of it, `showOptions'` which uses my custom `Lens.para` which is called `paraApp`. The difference is that this one passes a `Pretext` along with the data as it does its work so that later I can adjust my code to make use of this `Pretext` to adjust the original data structure if need be.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, TemplateHaskell, ExplicitForAll, DeriveDataTypeable, StandaloneDeriving #-}

module StepThree where

import qualified Control.Lens as Lens
import qualified Data.Data as DD
import qualified Data.Data.Lens as DDL
import qualified Data.Maybe as DM
import qualified Data.List as DL
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import StepThreeGrammar (EExp(..), pretty, run)

import Control.Comonad.Store.Class (pos, peek, ComonadStore)
import Control.Lens.Internal.Context (Pretext(..), sell)

import qualified Language.Haskell.Interpreter as I
import Language.Haskell.Interpreter (Interpreter, GhcError(..), InterpreterError(..))

instance DD.Data a => Lens.Plated (EExp a)
deriving instance DD.Data a => DD.Data (EExp a)

eg3' :: EExp Int
eg3' = EAdd (EAdd (EAdd (EAdd (EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)) (ELit 3)) (ELit 1)) (ELit 5)) (ELit 0)

showOptions :: (Lens.Plated a, Show a) => (a -> String) -> a -> [String]
showOptions showFn = Lens.para $ \a xs ->
    let
      sa = showFn a
      (_,is) = DL.mapAccumL mapAccumFn (0, sa) xs
    in
      sa : concat is
  where
    mapAccumFn (n, acc) x =
      let
        i = pfxIndex (head x) acc
      in
        ( (n+i+length (head x)
          , drop (i+length (head x)) acc)
        , map (replicate (n+i) ' ' ++) x)


showOptions' :: (Lens.Plated a, Show a) => (a -> String) -> a -> [String]
showOptions' showFn = paraApp $ \(a, ctx) xs ->
    let
      sa = showFn a
      (_, is) = DL.mapAccumL mapAccumFn (0, sa) xs
    in
      sa : concat is
  where
    mapAccumFn (n, acc) x =
      let
        i = pfxIndex (head x) acc
      in
        ( (n+i+length (head x)
          , drop (i+length (head x)) acc)
        , map (replicate (n+i) ' ' ++) x)

paraApp :: Lens.Plated a => ((a, Pretext (->) a a a) -> [r] -> r) -> a -> r
paraApp f x = go id (x, makePretextFocussingOnSelfFor x)
  where
    go p a =
      let p' = Lens.plate . p
          holes = Lens.holesOf p' x
      in f a (go p' <$> (map (\c -> (pos c, c)) holes))
    makePretextFocussingOnSelfFor x = Pretext ($ x)


pfxIndex :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Int
pfxIndex x y = maybe 0 id (DL.findIndex (x `DL.isPrefixOf`) (DL.tails y))
```

If I go into `GHCi` and execute the following code, it provides the intended output:

```
*Main EditorTest StepThree Control.Lens> mapM_ putStrLn $ StepThree.showOptions show eg3'
EAdd (EAdd (EAdd (EAdd (EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)) (ELit 3)) (ELit 1)) (ELit 5)) (ELit 0)
      EAdd (EAdd (EAdd (EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)) (ELit 3)) (ELit 1)) (ELit 5)
            EAdd (EAdd (EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)) (ELit 3)) (ELit 1)
                  EAdd (EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)) (ELit 3)
                        EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)
                              ELit 11
                                        ELit 9
                                                  ELit 3
                                                            ELit 1
                                                                      ELit 5
                                                                                ELit 0
```

Which is fine for the case when I don't want to do anything with a context (say updating a particular piece of the original value)

So when I attempt the replacement function, the following happens (it should be identical to the above):

```
    *Main EditorTest StepThree Control.Lens> mapM_ putStrLn $ StepThree.showOptions' show eg3'
    EAdd (EAdd (EAdd (EAdd (EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)) (ELit 3)) (ELit 1)) (ELit 5)) (ELit 0)
          EAdd (EAdd (EAdd (EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)) (ELit 3)) (ELit 1)) (ELit 5)
                EAdd (EAdd (EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)) (ELit 3)) (ELit 1)
                      EAdd (EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)) (ELit 3)
                            EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)
                                  ELit 11
                                            ELit 9
                                                      ELit 3
                                                      ELit 11
                                                             ELit 9
                                                                ELit 1
                                                                EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)
                                                                      ELit 11
                                                                                ELit 9
                                                                                       ELit 3
                                                                                       ELit 11
                                                                                              ELit 9
                                                                          ELit 5
                                                                          EAdd (EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)) (ELit 3)
                                                                                EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)
                                                                                      ELit 11
                                                                                                ELit 9
                                                                                                          ELit 3
                                                                                                          ELit 11
                                                                                                                 ELit 9
                                                                                                                 ELit 1
                                                                                                                 EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)
                                                                                                                       ELit 11
                                                                                                                                 ELit 9
                                                                                                                                        ELit 3
                                                                                                                                        ELit 11
                                                                                                                                               ELit 9
                                                                                    ELit 0
                                                                                    EAdd (EAdd (EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)) (ELit 3)) (ELit 1)
                                                                                          EAdd (EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)) (ELit 3)
                                                                                                EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)
                                                                                                      ELit 11
                                                                                                                ELit 9
                                                                                                                          ELit 3
                                                                                                                          ELit 11
                                                                                                                                 ELit 9
                                                                                                                                    ELit 1
                                                                                                                                    EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)
                                                                                                                                          ELit 11
                                                                                                                                                    ELit 9
                                                                                                                                                           ELit 3
                                                                                                                                                           ELit 11
                                                                                                                                                                  ELit 9
                                                                                                                                           ELit 5
                                                                                                                                           EAdd (EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)) (ELit 3)
                                                                                                                                                 EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)
                                                                                                                                                       ELit 11
                                                                                                                                                                 ELit 9
                                                                                                                                                                           ELit 3
                                                                                                                                                                           ELit 11
                                                                                                                                                                                  ELit 9
                                                                                                                                                                                  ELit 1
                                                                                                                                                                                  EAdd (ELit 11) (ELit 9)
                                                                                                                                                                                        ELit 11
                                                                                                                                                                                                  ELit 9
                                                                                                                                                                                                         ELit 3
                                                                                                                                                                                                         ELit 11
                                                                                                                                                                                                                ELit 9
```

Obviously I have my recursion wrong somewhere, but I can't work it out. As always, any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you're not familiar with the original definition of `Lens.para`, it can be found at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/src/Control.Lens.Plated.html#para

Comment: How exactly does the 2nd example go wrong? What are the intended semantics of `showOptions` and `showOptions'`? I have no idea what it means to "provide lensed contexts to the para function as it does its work". `Pretext (->) a a a` is really just `(a, a -> a)` and I'm not sure what that represents - you don't even use the `ctx` in your implementation of `showOptions'`! If you don't need that `ctx`, what is the point of your `paraApp`?

Comment: Sorry about that I thought I was pretty clear. The output is supposed to be identical. `Pretext` is like a `Context` from the `Control.Lens.Plated` library in that it's a lens applied to a value. It lets us use `pos` to get the focussed data out (like a getter), or `peek` to adjust the original structure (like a setter). I know I'm not using `ctx` in my implementation of `showOptions'` — I mentioned it above — it's so that I *can* use it when I need to next up (otherwise I'd just use `showOptions`.

Comment: What I meant by "provide lensed contexts to the para function as it does its work" is ... the paramorphism function takes a function which it calls on the `plate` contexts of whatever level is currently being focussed on.  That second function usually takes two values: the next `plate` value, and a list of the results so far. This is what a paramorphism is. If the function returns a list, those then get focussed on, too. *My* version of `para` rather passes a tuple of the next plate value and the Pretext of that value related to the original structure. This is so that later on I can use it.

Comment: The definition for `Lens.para` can be found at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/src/Control.Lens.Plated.html#para

Comment: I think I'm starting to see the problem now. Because I'm doing the depth traversal by using repeated composition on `Lens.plate` directly with relation to the original value, rather than on each sub-value, like `Lens.para` does, it's causing the recursion explosion. I'll have to find a way to only apply to the `holes` that are needed in each case. Would still value anyone's input if they have any.

Comment: Ok so I think I need to use `holesOnOf` instead of `holesOf` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has taken me on a very interesting journey which I'm still on. I'm pretty sure the answer lies in creating a new function that merges the functionality of `Lens.paraOf plate` with that of `Lens.contexts`. At least I know the problem now and much more about Context and recursion schemes. I'd suggest anyone who is interested in writing this function should look into the source of those.

So, to answer the question, the error in the recursion lies in the fact that I'm using fmap (`<$>`) to map **every single** *upper* lens over **every single** child in the *lower* part of structure. That means that each subtree, rather than only getting the recursion into its particular part of the tree, is getting the full recursion into every part of the tree.

A correct implementation would take this into consideration.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16643822)

Comment: I *am* the author lol. But yeah, I'll amend the answer to actually answer the question, which is asking where the error lies in the recursion.

Comment: Thanks. The comments are 'canned' and inserted by the review system